# Ubuntu 16.04 Firefox can't play some video despite flash installed

Tags: 16.04, firefox, flash, firefox-extensions

I'm facing an issue with Firefox 59.0.2 in Ubuntu 16.04 (up to date): Some video simply won't play.

All youtube videos work, but the following doesn't work (it loads forever):
https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/89uxbm/this_is_without_a_doubt_the_hardest_shrine/

It works in both Google Chrome and Opera. Is this a Flash problem? (I think both Chrome and Opera include their own flash renderer).

I already have adobe-flashplugin installed on my system.

Could you please help me troubleshoot this issue?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Which version does this link report?  https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

Comment: Installing [browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html#browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash) may be worth a try.

Comment: The link tells me "Sorry, Flash Player is either not installed or not enabled."

I tried removing and reinstalling adobe-flashplugin, no luck.
I also tried installing from the link (APT), which tells me "adobe-flashplugin is already installed".

Comment: FYI the video does work with Firefox version 58 on my 16.04 system.  The video type is "video/mp4" shown by "view page info" then "media". The direct link is `https://v.redd.it/ag1lpm9dczp01/DASH_600_K` It should be using "OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc. version 1.7.1" plugin.

Comment: @Eric Sorry for taking so long to get back to you.  I had experience the same problem on all my computers with Gnome, Chromium and Firefox... even new installs.  Today I began working on it again.  It worked on my main computer.  It worked with all the browsers.  I went to the other computers in my shop and it's working on all of them.  I didn't make any changes on the computers, except for my main computer.  All the other computers were a default install.  So I can only infer there must have been a chance to Amazon.  Are you still having problems?

Comment: Hi! Yes, still facing the issue. I just had a youtube video refusing to start for the first time. I checked their html5 page (https://www.youtube.com/html5) and it says h264 isn't supported. I have installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and x264, but it still doesn't work. As usual, no problem with Chrome and opera.